# Change value within a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:@"1"];
NSString *test = array[0];
test = @"2";
NSLog(@"%@", array[0]); //Output is 1

array[0] = @"2";
NSLog(@"%@", array[0]); //Output is 2
```

Whats going on ? Why in first case output is 1 ? Doesn't NSMutableArrat keeps links to an objects ?

Comment: Welcome to world of pointers. Why are you confused? Did you come here from `Swift`?

Answer (score 2):

> Whats going on ?

`test` and `array[0]` are different object references that point to the same object when you do:

```
NSString *test = array[0];
```

When you assign `test` to `@"2"` you point it to a different object:

```
test = @"2";
```

You don't change the object reference at `array[0]` until:

```
array[0] = @"2";
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define your array and add your first element to it:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:@"1"];
```

your storage looks like this:

[image: Storage after adding the first element to it]

Now when you define a `NSString` variable like this

```
NSString *test = array[0];
```

you create a **pointer** `test` that points to the first array element. However, it **is not** the first array element. It just points to it.

[image: Storage after defining and assigning the test string pointer]

With

```
test = @"2";
```

you let your `test` pointer point to a string `@"2"`. So you simply assign a new value (address) to your string pointer.

[image: Storage after modifying the test string pointer]

Thus, after this line `test` doesn't know anything about the array anymore and the array element won't be modified by this line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but NSString is not mutable, and you are not just changing it's value: when you do this:

```
test = @"2";
```

you create a new pointer with a new value `@"2"`

and so from now on

`array[0]` is a different pointer, it's not more the same pointer you added to your array

you can try this, to better understand:

```
NSMutableString* test = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"1"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject: test];

NSLog(@"test 1: %@", array[0]); //Output is 1
[test setString:@"2"];
NSLog(@"test 2: %@", array[0]); //Output is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is code that you need:

```
NSArray *array = @[[@"1" mutableCopy]];
NSMutableString *test = array[0];
[test setString:@"2"];
NSLog(@"%@", array[0]); //Output is 2
```

It's happen because:

```
test = @"2"
```

creates new object and assign it's pointer to variable `test`, but `array` still have pointer at old object, you haven't changed it yet.

My code uses the same object, storied in array, to modify value, so it's also got modified in `array`.